# sorting array of arrays in descending order using arrays.sort function is resulting in errors in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator, greedy

problem:https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-units-on-a-truck/
I am supposed to sort array of arrays of size 2(eg. [[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]]) in descending order according to 2nd value of the inner element. i.e for 1st element[1,3]according to value 3. , but my code is resulting in error: no suitable method found for sort().Some Help would be appreciated.

here is my code in java

```
class Solution {
    public int maximumUnits(int[][] boxTypes, int truckSize) {
        Arrays.sort(boxTypes, new Comparator<int[][]>() {
                    public int compare(final int[][] entry1, final int[][] entry2) {
                        if (entry1[0][0] < entry2[0][0])
                            return 1;
                        else return -1;
                    }
                }
        );
        for (int i = 0; i < boxTypes.length; i++)
            System.out.println(boxTypes[i]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're trying to sort an `int[][]`, your comparator should compare elements of that array. Those have type `int[]`, not `int[][]`. You should also consider returning 0 if the two entries are equal, otherwise your sorting will be unpredictable at best, or even fail with an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are sorting by inner element, which is `int[]`, so you need `Comparator<int[]>`.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] input = new int[][]{new int[]{2, 2}, new int[]{1, 3}, new int[]{3, 1}};
        Arrays.sort(input, new Comparator<int[]>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o2[1], o1[1]);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));
    }
}
```

Note `return Integer.compare(o2[1], o1[1]);`, second parameter is compared to first in order to achieve descending order.

You could also achieve same effect using lambda, to make it shorter and more readable.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] input = new int[][]{new int[]{2, 2}, new int[]{1, 3}, new int[]{3, 1}};
        System.out.println("Initial array - " + Arrays.deepToString(input));
        Arrays.sort(input, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o2[1], o1[1]));
        System.out.println("Sorted array - " + Arrays.deepToString(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help! however I didn't understand why you needed the deeptostring function for printing the array?

Comment: @smit `Arrays.toString()` will print the array in this format - `[[I@b4c966a, [I@2f4d3709, [I@4e50df2e]`. Each element is `int[]`, but arrays don't have `toString()` override, so elements will be string-ified using default behaviour.

Comment: got it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use native type in `<>`, you need to use `Integer` instead. Then what you need to compare is the inner array `Integer[]` if I'm not mistaken so your comparator can't work. Here you are just trying to sort 2 arrays of arrays based on the first element of the first array.

Here is what I would do (using stream):

```
Integer[][] sortedBoxTypes = Arrays.stream(boxTypes).sorted(Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry[1])).toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```

Comment: `you can't use native type in <>, you need to use Integer instead` - this is wrong. You can use primitive arrays as generic type. `Comparator<int[]>` is a valid declaration. Also question is about sorting with `Arrays.sort()`, not streams.

Comment: Ok,  my mistake for the native type: sorry about that.  Stream was just another way of doing it, of course the comparator I used can be used also without stream: `Arrays.sort(input, Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry[1]));`